# Read Downloaded Text File - FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, json, filenotfoundexception

plz help, I'm trying to get the data from this google translate API URL
and it works only if the value is 1 word.. if its 2 it gives me an error..

i mean this will values will work:

```
String sourceLang = "auto";
String targetLang = "en";
String sourceText = "olas";
String urlstring = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + sourceText;
```

but if i put it with 2 words:

```
String sourceText = "olas olas";
```

it will gives me the filenotfoundexception error

this is the code:

```
        URL url = new URL(urlstring);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLconnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36");
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLconnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while(line != null){
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;
        }
```

Comment: you can't have a space in url , that is the reason its giving error make sure you have valid file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace space with "%20" like

```
urlstring=urlstring.replace(" ", "%20");

URL url = new URL(urlstring);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLconnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36");
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLconnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while(line != null){
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;
        }
```